# Android: Force dialog themed activity to be modal

Tags: android, dialog

A button on our screen causes an activity to be shown that has a "dialog" theme.  We are having an issue were if you click the button quickly twice in a row, the dialog activity is opened twice.

Typically I would expect that when a new activity is started, the underlying activity is immediately stopped, and thus accepts no further input.

However, since the dialog themed activity does not take over the whole screen, I think the underlying activity is only paused, not stopped and thus the buttons are still accessible.

Which brings me to my question... Is there a way to force the dialog themed activity into a modal state where the user can't click the buttons on the activity below?

I could probably manually accomplish this by disabling everything in onPause, and reenabling it in onResume, but this seems like a lot of work!  Anyone have an easier solution?

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of disabling things (which seens hacky and wrong), but if there isn't a real solution. The disabling could be done with a simple return in the button click event. As long as you reset the bool when the dialog returns or in onResume

```
boolean clicked;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (clicked)
                return;
            clicked = true;
            // show dialog
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  That would indeed work, I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't involve custom code on every touchable item though..

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to not launch your activity with a dialog theme but a standard one.  In your XML for the activity specify, say a textview, that occupies the entire screen.  However make the textview transparent (or semi or colored or ....) and clickable.

Then, in the same xml file, make your "dialog" so that it displays on top of the textview.  Now it looks like a dialog, the activity behind it can still be seen, but clicks outside of your dialog are are consumed by the transparent textview.  For example:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/ViewHider"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#aa000000"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    ></TextView>

<!-- Then put your "dialog" xmal here -->
```

Comment: When I do this the background is always black and I can't see the activity underneath.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post some code/xml?  The background color might need a greater transparency level to see the underlying activity.  (Off the top of my head)